# how to cherry-pick custom individual commits or commits ranges?

Tags: git

I wanted to cherry-pick custom commits and ranges like `git cherry-pick head~1 head~4..head~67 head~87 head~9 head~120..head~145` this but git didn't give me a optimal result, so I know we can cherry-pick multiple individual commits together but when it comes to multiple commits ranges or the combination of ranges and individual commits it doesn't work properly? so If there is a solution, does it apply to `git revert`?

Comment: I only _once_ tried to cherry-pick separate ranges in a single shot in my life.... I don't think I got what I needed so I ended up running ranges separately.... A single range works like a charm, in my experience.... I always get what I expect.

Comment: same experience in here, I was thinking to work with these ranges separately but I wanted to get sure is there whether is there another answer or not...@eftshift0

Comment: I guess you'd have to elaborate on "*git didn't give me a optimal result*".

Comment: for example we have `git cherry-pick head~4 head~6..head~9`, so I expect to have cherry-picked commits in this order: head~4 head~7 head~8 head~9 but it's not in this order and sometimes it even includes some other commits which they aren't part of the specific commits I have used inside the command.@RomainValeri

Comment: Unexpected indeed, but I'd suggest to add a detailed version of this (ideally a minimal reproducible example) to the question.